# How do I input an image name into a function in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, function

Basically, what I'm trying to do is run the following function directly from the command window in MATLAB. My function itself is:

```
function reconstruct_2(im_input,d,c,k)
rgbpic = imread(im_input);
```

And the code being typed into the command window is:

```
reconstruct_2(image.png,1,1,3)
```

Currently I'm just getting the error:

```
Undefined variable "image" or function "image.png".
```

I don't know how to declare the image as an image or anything like that, so any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the image name as a string;

```
reconstruct_2('image.png',1,1,3)
```

See [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) on `imread`.